# Solr Core creates write.lock on startup and is never removed

Tags: solr

I've created a new core on Solr 7.1.0, and I start Solr by running `solr start`. As soon as I run this command, it creates a `write.lock` file in the index directory. This lockfile never gets deleted, and I have to delete it manually when restarting the core to avoid errors. I am only running 1 instance of Solr.

Edit: I'm running this on my local Windows 10 machine. I've tried using resmon to check if any processes are actually holding the `segments_1` file and did not find any.

Can someone provide me with insight on this behavior?

Comment: Are you running Solr from NFS or another networked file system?

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm running this only locally on Windows 10